# Prestashop 1.7 Update shipping cost programatically through ajax when changing payment method

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I have created one custom shipping module in Prestashop 1.7 which will list multiple shipping carriers (like DHL, Fedex etc) on checkout page and in-order to fetch their shipping cost, i am calling their respective API by passing parameters of products like Size,,Weight,Length,Width etc.. to fetch their shipping cost. https://prnt.sc/LzQlgXZdPv3W

Now if we select **Cash on Delivery** payment method then i need to again call shipping carrier api to fetch new shipping price as shipping price will be different based on **Cash on Delivery** Payment method. Because **COD** payment method will be having higher shipping price as compare with other payment methods like Credit Card, Debit card etc.

Can anyone know how we can achieve this functionality ? as i need to update shipping price (by calling their API) through ajax when we change payment method on checkout page.